# Does pounce let a Beast Shaped Druid rake even before Beast Shape grants rake?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat, druid

I have a player with a 7th level druid. Due to the wording of [Beast Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape) 2 and 3, pounce is granted for the 2nd, but rake is part of the 3rd.

After reading [pounce](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Pounce-Ex-), grab, and rake I'm a little confused. He has been trying to use the rake attack as part of pounce since pounce says it has it if the creature's form does. I've kindof ruled that he doesn't gain access to anything which lets him benefit from rake until 8th level when the spell would grant it.

So does the wording of pounce overrule the rake restriction in Beast Shape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pounce says:

> When a creature with this special attack makes a charge, it can make a full attack (including rake attacks **if the creature also has the rake ability**).

Considering that Beast Shape does not grant Rake until 8th level, the druid cant use Rake as part of a Pounce, because the druid (*the creature*) does not have the Rake ability.
Until 8th, he can do a full-attack during a charge, but not a Rake.

As a tip, remember that you should pretty much ignore the monster's stat block unless the spell grants him that specific ability.

Comment: That was what I thought. I just wasnt sure if pounce somehow allowed rake to be used in that specific circumstance.